# Automate map updating using data from a folder in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, python-script-tool

I'm trying to automate map updating in ArcGIS Pro using Python. Essentially, I need the program to read a folder with GeoJSON files, import them into a map, and update it. When I use the code below, the data is imported into the geodatabase, but it's not added to the map. There are no errors occurring.

```
def conversion():
arcpy.conversion.JSONToFeatures(
    in_json_file=r"D:\Programação\Python 3\pythonProject\Picarra.geojson",
    out_features=r"D:\Geoprocessamento\Projetos\Teste02\Teste02.gdb\Mapateste_JSONToFeatures2",
    geometry_type="POINT"
)
print('SUCESSO!')
```

[image: ArcGIS Pro Print Screen]

Comment: WHERE are you running the script?

Comment: Currently, I am running the script in PyCharm.

Comment: You need to edit your question and show the full script and how you are accessing the active project.

Comment: Actualy, this is the full script. Do you have any idea how can I do that?

Comment: That's your issue, you are just calling a tool. You need to run it within ArcPro so that it knows to add it to an active map. Try running your script inside the python command line window inside ArcPro.

Comment: Is there any way to do this in the Python program? I need this script to keep monitoring a folder that will be constantly updated with some files and import those files into the project, updating the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running code from inside ArcGIS has different behaviour than running code from outside (PyCharm). If you are running a script from outside of ArcGIS, then you need to also refer to the project, map and add the converted data to the map and finally save the aprx.
Code might look like this:

```
arx_file_path = 'some/path/here/project.aprx'
in_json_file=r"D:\Programação\Python 3\pythonProject\Picarra.geojson",
out_features=r"D:\Geoprocessamento\Projetos\Teste02\Teste02.gdb\Mapateste_JSONToFeatures2"

# get the aprx
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject(arx_file_path)
# get the map
m = aprx.listMaps("Your_Map_Name_HERE")[0]
# convert data
arcpy.conversion.JSONToFeatures(in_json_file,out_features,geometry_type="POINT")
# add data to map
m.addDataFromPath(out_features)
# save the aprx
aprx.save()
```

Comment: Or, if all your files have similar data, you don't add the feature to the map, you can re-source your layer in the map.

Comment: I didn't understand, could you please explain a bit more?

Comment: Now I have another issue: my code is returning the error "ERROR 000725: Output Feature Class: Dataset D:\Geoprocessing\Projects\Test02\Test02.gdb\Equipe1_JSONToFeatures already exists." Can you tell me what might be happening?